# Merge conflict -strange characters appearing

Tags: asp.net, git, git-merge

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC5 project and using vimdiff as my mergetool.

I am getting a merge conflict on a .csproj. This is not unexpected as files get added in different branches all of the time, however it seems that the process of merging is adding some junk data?

This is the state of the csproj on local, base and remote:

[image: Branch statuses]

And this is the apparent merge conflict:

[image: Extra characters at start of file]

As far as git is concerned the whole file is now a conflict...

```
<<<<<< HEAD
WHOLE CS PROJ FILE WITH CHARACTERS AT START
======
WHOLE CS PROJ FILE WITHOUT CHARACTERS AT START
>>>>>> develop
```

This obviously makes performing a proper merge kind of difficult.

I cannot see these characters in either branch before I try the merge.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), indicating that the file is encoded as UTF-8. It is only recognised at the start of a file, and since `<<<<<< HEAD` has been inserted before it, it is no longer at the start of the file, and has been made visible by a tool that does not detect / no longer detects the file as UTF-8.

Ensure that all tools you use to modify the file agree on whether the BOM should be there. If they all agree, then it should never cause a conflict. If some add the BOM when it isn't present, and others remove the BOM when it is present, conflicts are unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the lines you would not see in your source. `git add` the file(s) and make a commit, so you resolved a conflict.